# The method placeComponent() in the type PCB is not applicable for the arguments (HardwareComponent)

Tags: java

I'm trying to add Hardware Components to a PCB which contains arrays of objects and I am not able to pass the object to the array. This is my first Java Project so total newbie here. Please Help!

```
public class PCB {
    private Collection<HardwareComponent> hwComponents = new Vector<HardwareComponent>();
    private Collection<CircuitPath> connections = new Vector<CircuitPath>();

    public void placeComponent(<HardwareComponent> hw) {
        hwComponents.add(hw);
    }
```

And my Main

```
 public class Configurator {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        PCB pcb = new PCB();

        HardwareComponent c1 = new Capacitor("cap1", 0.55f);
        HardwareComponent c2 = new Capacitor("cap2", 0.22f);
        HardwareComponent c3 = new Capacitor("cap3", 0.50f);
        HardwareComponent c4 = new Capacitor("cap4", 0.75f);
        HardwareComponent r1 = new Resistor("res1", 0.14f);
        HardwareComponent r2 = new Resistor("res2", 0.18f);
        HardwareComponent r3 = new Resistor("res3", 0.17f);
        HardwareComponent r4 = new Resistor("res4", 0.10f);

        pcb.placeComponent(c1);
```

I'm getting this error:
The method placeComponent() in the type PCB is not applicable for the arguments (HardwareComponent)

No idea where to go from here, do I need to make a separate constructor for the class PCB or how do I pass the HardwareComponent to the method placeComponent?

Thank you in advance

Comment: why do you have <HardwareComponent> instead of HardwareComponent?

Comment: I thought that it was supposed to be like that, guess I was wrong :/

Comment: If you look at it, it took you more time, effort to get an answer/comment from SO than looking at the java reference.

Comment: I was looking at it and trying to solve it for quite a while before I asked here and I got an answer within minutes.

Comment: Ok. Notice the “quite a while”  but as you please. Logging off

Comment: As far as I know this forum is made for asking programming related questions. That's exactly what I did. If you have a problem with that, maybe you shouldn't lurk around here. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method signature is faulty
`public void placeComponent(<HardwareComponent> hw)`.
Try with
`public void placeComponent(HardwareComponent hw)`